# Card.io on Android doesn't show scan option in release mode

Tags: android, release, proguard, card.io

We're developing an Android app with Card.IO integrated in it.
It works fine in the debug mode and shows scan option, however when we make a release build, the scan option disappears and instead the user can only enter the card number manually and it's not what we need.

When we make the release build, we specify in the Android manifest file:

```
<application android:debuggable="false" ...
```

And as written in [docs](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) we add the following to the proguard file:

```
-keep class io.card.**
-keepclassmembers class io.card.** {
    *;
}
```

Comment: Jeff from Card.io here.  I was able to reproduce the issue.  It appears the camera hardware detection is a bit wonky in release mode.  I'll update this issue when I find a fix.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I hope it'll be a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We released [3.1.3](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/releases/tag/3.1.3) of the card.io Android sdk card.io with a fix to this problem.  Please feel free to open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues) if you still require additional help.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too. It was on a Samsung G2 and a Samsung G3 that card.io was not working.