# card.io doesn't work in production

Tags: android, eclipse, card.io

card.io works great when installed from eclipse.
when installed exported apk the activity throws this: ERROR_NO_DEVICE_SUPPORT: This device cannot use the camera to read card numbers.

1. tried to disable proguard and export.
2. opened apk file to verify .so files are there in the correct folders under lib.
3. this is happening on 3 different devices, nexus 4, samsung s3, alcatel.

the project with card.io is a library project used by other android projects.

any ideas?
thanks,
sharon.

Comment: Did you give your application all the permissions it needs?

Comment: yes, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET, CAMERA. Don't think it would have worked in debug mode without permissions.

Comment: Which version of the card.io sdk are you using?  Please download the latest version, as some older versions have had some [issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265792/card-io-on-android-doesnt-show-scan-option-in-release-mode?rq=1) in release mode.

Comment: thanks Jeff, should have tried it :)

Comment: would you like to add your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [download](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) the latest version (3.1.3+), as some older Android card.io versions had [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265792/card-io-on-android-doesnt-show-scan-option-in-release-mode?rq=1) in release mode.